# My Scrapy CrawlSpider stops after the initial start URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My spider looks like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "craig"
# allowed_domains = ["support.t-mobile.com/community/phones-tablets-devices/"]
# start_urls = ["https://support.t-mobile.com/community/phones-tablets-devices/apple/content?start=20&filterID=contentstatus%5Bpublished%5D~objecttype~objecttype%5Bthread%5D"]

allowed_domains = ["reddit.com/rising/"]
start_urls = ["https://www.reddit.com/rising/"]


rules = [
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True),
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse')
]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response) 
    item = CraigslistSampleItem()
    # item['link'] = hxs.xpath('//td[@class = "j-td-title"]/div/a/@href').extract()
    # item['title'] = hxs.xpath('//td[@class = "j-td-title"]/div/a/text()').extract()
    # item['content'] = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="jive-rendered-content"]/p/text()').extract()
    item['URL'] = response.request.url
    print item
```

If you see I have not specified any allowed paths or restricted path. This should make the spider crawl through all the links. Can someone please tell me why my Spider stops after the initial page.

The console output looks like this :

```
2016-10-25 14:36:38 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: 

craigslist_sample)
2016-10-25 14:36:38 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2016-10-25 14:36:38 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'craigslist_sample.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['craigslist_sample.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'craigslist_sample'}
2016-10-25 14:36:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-10-25 14:36:38 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2016-10-25 14:36:39 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1228, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1198, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2016-10-25 14:36:39 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2016-10-25 14:36:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-10-25 14:36:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-10-25 14:36:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-10-25 14:36:39 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-10-25 14:36:39 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-10-25 14:36:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-10-25 14:36:40 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.reddit.com/rising/> (referer: None)
2016-10-25 14:36:40 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-10-25 14:36:40 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 219,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 24786,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 25, 18, 36, 40, 242330),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 25, 18, 36, 39, 525046)}
2016-10-25 14:36:40 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found three problems in your code:

(1) `allowed_domains`. `allowed-domain` is used to filter out of site links and itself should be a valid [Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Domain_name_syntax). Please change it to:

```
allowed_domains = ['reddit.com']
```

(2) `parse` callback. `parse` is the [default callback](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse) of response when their request do not specify callback. Please rename it, e.g., as `parse_item` and rename `parse` function to `parse_item` as well. Please read the [Warning](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule):

> Warning
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

(3) About `Rule`. I don't quiet understand your rule. Please read the [Rule documents](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule)

> rule
>
> Which is a list of one (or more) Rule objects. Each Rule defines a certain behaviour for crawling the site. Rules objects are described below. If multiple rules match the same link, the first one will be used, according to the order they’re defined in this attribute.
>
> follow
>
> follow is a boolean which specifies if links should be followed from each response extracted with this rule. If callback is None follow defaults to True, otherwise it defaults to False.

In your code:

```
rules = [
    # allow all links (in allowed_domains), and follow them, and not parse
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True),
    # allow all links (in allowed_domains), and not follow, and call parse to parse
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse')
    ]
```

Obliviously, your rules are conflict, if you want to follow all links and parse them all, use the following code:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')
]
```

Here is a sample code that is works for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class RedditSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "reddit"
    allowed_domains = ["reddit.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.reddit.com/rising/"]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        pass
```

Hope my explanation is helpful. Thanks!